# Impossible to copy light font?

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

I tried to copy the font of this [website](http://themes.fastwp.net/memphis1/?page_id=2487) menu but when I put the style in my own WordPress CSS theme I still get the bold version of it. Is there a special trick so I can get the light version of the font?
Got the font the same way loaded in what they have.

Comment: Please appoint a correct answer so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 5):

If you are indeed looking for the font Montserrat and you want the light version, you can use this import reference:

```
@import url(http://allfont.net/allfont.css?fonts=montserrat-light);
```

And you can use it like this in css:

```
font-family: 'Montserrat Light', arial;
```

More information about this font can be found here: http://allfont.net/download/montserrat-light/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Google font *Montserrat*:

http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Montserrat

It seems this font only comes in Normal (400) and **Bold** (700):

http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Montserrat

For the Normal version of the font, try adding:

```
font-weight: 400;
```

to your CSS. Also, make sure you're referencing the font correctly by importing it first:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
```

then adding the style to the correct element:

```
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
```